# Windows command line error with Node.js

Tags: cmd.exe, node.js

I am trying to install connect.js in my computer. After installing Node.js using the .msi installation file (i.e. npm has already been installed along with it) the Windows cmd window shows this error:

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: javascript files are processed by a browser or served (sent) to a client connected to say Apache or IIS then processed by their browser.  **Your question is not exactly clear**

Comment: [8 Learning Node.js Video Training - Stay up to date and find the help you need](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DoU_kW2perw&index=8&list=PLzJZ3ahfm9Q9kwUuoJadCgNlgnCR4xYwp)

Comment: @Karel.Thanks for the input.I can make use of this

Answer (score 2):

By default node installs into `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs` and adds itself to the PATH variable. If you have done a default installation of node.js (i.e. [Node.js Windows Installer (.msi)](http://nodejs.org/download/)), it can be started from the command prompt by typing `node`.

From the cmd window type:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs"
npm install connect
```

If you have installed node.js to  a different directory, instead of "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs" substitute the path to nodejs in the first command.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.I did as you suggested.It is not showing me any error anymore.But when i type "npm install connect",the server still does not show. I am wondering what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: At what point during or after you run `npm install connect` does the server still not show? Can you run the "Hello World" example found at http://nodejs.org/ using the "Hello World" code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737824/how-to-run-a-hello-js-file-in-node-js-on-windows/6738741#6738741)? This simple web server written in Node responds with "Hello World" for every request.

Comment: Thanks for your response.After loading the code to example.js,i run it on window command.Here is what i got

Comment: Thanks for your response.Server NEVER show at all.After loading the code to example.js,i run it on window command.Here is what i got  C:\WINDOWS\system32>node example.js     mode.js:340 throw err;   Error:cannot find module C:\WINDOWS\system32\example.js   at Function.Module_resolveFilename(module.js:338:15)  at function.module_load(module.js:2:25)  at function.module.runmain(module.js:497:10)  at startup (node.js:119:16) at node.j:906:3

Comment: I really dont know what i am doing wrong with this.I need help

Comment: To run the server, put the code into a file example.js, put the example.js file in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs` directory, at the command line prompt type `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs"` and execute it with the node program from the command line. The result of executing example.js should be: `http://127.0.0.1:1337/` in the cmd window. Now visit `http://127.0.0.1:1337/` in your default web browser and you should see a webpage that says: `Hello World` .

Comment: Another way to do it is to make a separate folder anywhere on your computer, call it Nodejs_Projects or whatever other name you like, put all your Node.js projects in that folder and then from the command line `cd` to the Nodejs_Projects before you run any Node.js project file that is in that folder.

Comment: Karel, Thanks.Strangely, here is what i got after doing what you suggested.After putting the example.js in the directory,i checked by clicking the files(i wrote the code into notepad+++) to make sure it is correct.The notepad+++ displayed C:\Program Files(x86)\nodejs\example.js. But when i wrote it(cd "C:Program Files (x86)\nodejs"\example.js)at window command,it shows THE SYSTEM CANNOT FIND THE PATH SPECIFIED.I sincerely appreciate your help here but i still need further help on this.

Comment: The correct command to use is `cd "C:Program Files (x86)\nodejs"`, not `cd "C:Program Files (x86)\nodejs"\example.js` . That's why you got the error message. When your current directory in the cmd window is `C:Program Files (x86)\nodejs` Windows can find any of the files that are in that directory.

Comment: Thanks.I will fix that and get back to you.In the interim,what do you mean by "execute it with the node program from the command line."

Comment: To execute example.js from the command line, cd to the directory that contains example.js and then execute it by running the command `node example.js`. The output of this command should be `Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/` and then when you open your default web browser to `http://127.0.0.1:1337/` it should have a webpage with text that says: `Hello World`.

Comment: Thanks.I am frustrated because at the command prompt and after typing the command line(cd "C:Program Files (x86)\nodejs) it shows The SYSTEM CANNOT FIND THE PATH SPECIFIED'" I really dont know what is going on anymore.I use administrator:command prompt.

Comment: You still didn't type the right path. The right command to use is `cd "C:Program Files (x86)\nodejs"`, not `cd "C:Program Files (x86)\nodejs`. You don't know how to copy/paste text in the cmd window if I'm not mistaken and that is why you're frustrated. I've read that Microsoft has added this feature to Windows 10. That feature should make a lot of money for them.

Comment: See, it is the same i wrote at the command prompt.I only missed the " when typing here. So, i wrote very the same command line of cd "C:Program Files (x86)\nodejs" but it gave me the same thing The SYSTEM CANNOT FIND THE PATH SPECIFIED

Comment: OK, put example.js anywhere on your computer, for example on your desktop so you can see it. Then cd to the directory where you put example.js and execute `node example.js`. It doesn't matter where you put example.js as long as you cd to that directory before you run `node example.js`.

Comment: Yep.I got it. I cant thank you enough.I am grateful for your wonderful help. What i did was that i looked for the path that is creating this problem.Found it and copied and pasted it.Thanks once again.

Comment: For future reference, @afriend and karel: consider using a chatroom for extended discussions, the realtime responses are better and it helps to keep the question page a little more open. I'm glad you guys got it figured out - kudos to all for helping out! :)

Comment: @karel.Yes. I am very much interested in learning more about nod.js and all its important npm. As a matter of act, i am trying to develop an application using nodejs,socket.io and Express.

Comment: @studiohack,i would love to chat myself. But when i tried to do that yesterday, it showed that i could not be cause i need 20 reputations to do that. And i am relatively new here.